# PayPal.fetchDeviceReferenceTokenWithAppID() causes NullPointerException on Nexus 7

Tags: android, paypal

I am using PayPal's MECL library in one of my projects and it has been tested and worked as intended on half a dozen devices. However when I tested it on Nexus 7 an NullPointerException is always thrown when the `PayPal.fetchDeviceReferenceTokenWithAppID()` method is called:

> 07-24 23:26:11.466: W/System.err(28266):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 07-24 23:26:11.466:
>   W/System.err(28266):  at
>   libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132) 07-24 23:26:11.466:
>   W/System.err(28266):  at
>   java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57) 07-24 23:26:11.466:
>   W/System.err(28266):  at com.paypal.android.a.c.g(Unknown Source)
>   07-24 23:26:11.466: W/System.err(28266):  at
>   com.paypal.android.a.c.e(Unknown Source) 07-24 23:26:11.466:
>   W/System.err(28266):  at com.paypal.android.a.c.b(Unknown Source)
>   07-24 23:26:11.466: W/System.err(28266):  at
>   com.paypal.android.a.d.run(Unknown Source) 07-24 23:26:11.496:
>   D/TilesManager(28266): Starting TG #0, 0x672a6428 07-24 23:26:11.496:
>   D/TilesManager(28266): new EGLContext from framework: 693dbd88  07-24
>   23:26:11.496: D/GLWebViewState(28266): Reinit shader 07-24
>   23:26:11.506: D/GLWebViewState(28266): Reinit transferQueue 07-24
>   23:26:12.566: D/dalvikvm(28266): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1207K, 10% free
>   13335K/14688K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 55ms 07-24 23:26:13.136:
>   E/Error(28266): Authentication failed, button not enabled. 07-24
>   23:26:13.136: W/System.err(28266): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-24 23:26:13.136: W/System.err(28266):  at
>   com.paypal.android.a.c.a(Unknown Source) 07-24 23:26:13.136:
>   W/System.err(28266):  at com.paypal.android.a.c.e(Unknown Source)
>   07-24 23:26:13.136: W/System.err(28266):  at
>   com.paypal.android.a.c.b(Unknown Source) 07-24 23:26:13.136:
>   W/System.err(28266):  at com.paypal.android.a.d.run(Unknown Source)

Note that the exact same APK can run without issues on Galaxy Nexus, S3, and even the Nexus 7 emulator, it only stopped working on Nexus 7. I am at a complete loss at this stage so any help is welcome.

Comment: Does the sample app work on the Nexus 7? I'm guessing it won't, because this looks like an environmental problem.

Comment: It doesn't. What do you mean by environmental problem, and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up updating the app & server to use new PayPal Android API (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK), seem to be working on all devices now.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Paypal's MECL library but I would like to make a few general comments that might help you to solve this yourself.

In cases like this, the NPE is probably attributable to one of the following:

1) The NPE occurs because you have not linked all the requisite libraries in to your APK and the Nexus 7 is attempting to call something that the other devices are not. This is relatively unlikely, but a logcat trace for a successful device should prove or disprove this. i.e. if a logcat trace for your other device(s) show that PayPal.fetchDeviceReferenceTokenWithAppID works ok - then this is not the problem.

2) The NPE occurs because something is missing from your Nexus 7 (or needs to be updated). This is what I mean by an environmental problem. Check the Paypal documentation carefully for requisite software levels. If the sample app works on the other devices but not the Nexus 7 then this is the likely cause of the problem. Is it the case that MECL is not longer supported by Paypal ? - does this mean that a requisite update has been withdrawn ?PayPal.fetchDeviceReferenceTokenWithAppID looks like something that you would do at the start of a transaction, so I'm (still) guessing this is an environmental problem.

I can't tell you what your specific problem is, but hopefully this will help you make some progress.

Comment: As mentioned, PayPal.fetchDeviceReferenceTokenWithAppID worked perfectly on all other devices. And yeah MECL is no longer supported, but we are using it in this project for historical reasons. It's frustrating because the library is obfuscated so not only is it hard to determine the source of the issue, but that to fix it we'd probably have to decompile it ourselves and modify it that way.